# Ubuntu thinks I have two displays

Tags: display

When I first installed Ubuntu I noticed that my mouse would flicker a lot, which caused me to investigate. I remembered back when I ran Fedora I had an issue where it thought I had two displays (hp-dv7 4285dx laptop). In Fedora, this didn't cause any issues. In Ubuntu, it causes the mouse the flicker a lot. The fix I've been using is to just go into settings > displays and disable the display that doesn't actually exist. The only problem is that this is not permanent. Each time I start up Ubuntu, I have to go back in and disable this display. They're each just titled "Built-in Display", and have the same resolution.

My laptop does have two graphics cards: one on-board and one dedicated. I'm not sure if maybe that is causing is an issue? Any guidance towards this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have/had the same problem (Acer 3820TG laptop) with 2 video chipsets. Ubuntu 14.04.

Main problems were:

1. Cursor flickers or disappears completely.
2. I would launch programs and the window was on the other screen (I thought it hadn't launched correctly, urrgh!) so I couldn't see it.

As a workaround I selected `Mirror Displays` in `System Settings`/`Screen Display`.(Both screens reported identical attributes so no resolution conflict expected)

It gave me a problem warning but has fixed these problems. SO far its working but I don't know why it detects two in-built displays. Like you, I suspect the 2 graphics cards to one monitor are confusing it.

Answer (score 0):

I still occasionally get this issue running Zorin OS 15.3 on a 2015 MacBook Pro, (Zorin is built on Ubuntu). Occasionally a few pixels at the top of the screen flicker and/or the OS thinks there's a second monitor connected.

This isn't a fix, but I simply opened the settings app and the issue went away. It may be a fluke, but I'm guessing something initialized or re-evaluated the active monitors when I opened the settings app.